# Make the content of JavaScript and JSON powered review widget searchable in Google

Tags: seo, javascript, ajax

I have created a review widget, which can be injected on any page. The widget will help a page owner generate content from visitors reviews and questions. I have to make this content searchable on any search engine so that it helps in increasing the page owner's site traffic.

The content is stored in a separate database. Every time the page loads, review widget gets initiated which would pull data from server as JSON, build HTML on the fly using JavaScript on the browser and render reviews.

How do I make these reviews searchable?

Comment: Googlebot executes JavaScript sees data written into the page on load by AJAX now.   I don't think you need to do anything for Google at this point.   Other search engines are not as sophisticated yet though.